How to force server to use specific network interface for connecting to the server itself?
Context
I'm setting up a server that acts as a central logging collector. The logs are sent via rsyslog to a Fluentd Docker container, and I need it to also collect logs generated by the log collector server itself.
Problem
Due to specific logging management requirements, these local logs generated by the collector server should be sent to the container (which runs in host network mode) over the internal network interface (eth1) rather than the public network interface (eth0) in order to work with the appropiate internal IP address but, despite specifying the IP address of the eth1 interface, the connection is made with the IP address of the eth0 interface.
Troubleshooting
For debugging purposes, I am using ncat where the same issue is observed. Here’s what I tried:
root@myserver:~# ncat 10.114.0.5 500 # connect to eth1 IP

On the same server, I set up a listener to check incoming connections:
root@myserver:~# ncat -nlvp 500 # receive connection from eth0 IP
Ncat: Version 7.93 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::500
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:500
Ncat: Connection from 164.X.X.X.
Ncat: Connection from 164.X.X.X:41946.

Despite attempting to connect specifically to 10.114.0.5 (the IP associated with eth1), the incoming connections are registered as coming from the external IP (164.X.X.X).
Questions

Why is the connection not utilizing the specified internal
interface?
How can I force the server to use eth1 for sending logs
to itself?

Additional info
Server OS: Debian 12
Relevant interfaces
root@myserver:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a2:ac:35:ad:8d:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s3
    altname ens3
    inet 164.X.X.X/20 brd 164.X.X.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.19.0.8/16 brd 10.19.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a0ac:35ff:fead:8d99/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:14:3e:16:c0:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s4
    altname ens4
    inet 10.114.0.5/20 brd 10.114.15.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3014:3eff:fe16:c013/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:99:c8:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

IP routes
root@myserver:~# ip route show
default via 164.X.X.1 dev eth0 
10.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.19.0.8 
10.114.0.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.114.0.5 
10.114.0.0/20 dev br-4cd91dafbc4e proto kernel scope link src 10.114.0.1 linkdown 
10.114.0.5 dev eth1 scope link src 10.114.0.5 
164.X.X.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 164.X.X.X 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 

I have tried changing the default route, which I also don't think would make sense since there's another more prioritized one as well, but that hasn't had any effect either.
Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Edit the question and provide details on how the logs are being sent whether it is via an application, script, or something else. Also, how is the networking configured? Is one interface/address used by the default and the other one for fail over? What is the IP address of each interface?

Edited, thanks for the suggestion!

I'm pretty sure that's because you have an SNAT rule in your iptables (or an snat rule in your nftables) that sets the source IP to 164.X.X.X for traffics from 10.114.0.0/20 (or, all traffics, so to speak). A MASQUERADE / masquerade rule that does not have any condition that would make the case of loopback traffics excluded could cause you the problem as well (because 127.0.0.1 is "not an option" to it; so the first / primary address of the next interface, namely eth0 is used).
Solutions would be:

adding ! -o lo (oifname != "lo" for nftables) to the rule, or
adding -o eth0 (oifname "eth0" for nftables) to the rule (assuming the interface name is "static")

P.S. For nftables, depending on "details" of your system / distro, you might be able to use oif instead of oifname (especially when the name in concern is lo) for better performace (well, theoretically / technically speaking, at least).

Removing a conflictive MASQUERADE rule did the trick, as shown below. Many thanks for your help

As mentioned in the solution, the problem was caused by a MASQUERADE rule in iptables:
root@myserver:~# iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.114.0.0/20        anywhere

By removing this last rule, the source IP received when connecting to a service on the eth1 IP is precisely the eth1 IP.
